# Give WP-Cli User Home Directory Privileges

Tags: wp-cli

I am on an Ubuntu 18.04 local dev environment, running a WP Multisite 5.5.3

Three Part Question:

1.) What (who) is the WP-Cli user?   And,

2.) How do I give that user permission to "my_user's" home directory?

3.) Should I be worried from a security standpoint about giving the WP-Cli home directory access?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I will accept the "newbie" embarrassment and answer my basic questions . ;-)

1.) www-data

2.) For fellow wp-cli newbies, [follow this excellent tutorial to get wp-cli working in local dev](https://www.alexgeorgiou.gr/wp-cli-www-data-user-permissions-linux/),  and remember NOT to forget the last step. :-)

3.) One should never put the html directory in /home/ for the reason malicious actors could use www-data/php to go beyond the html directory to explore the contents of the user's home directory. However, www-data to having access to .wp-cli located in the home directory, still not clear of the security risk level, seems debatable.